# cartalyst/converter on laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, cartalyst

I'm trying to setup cartalyst/converter on laravel 5.6 Their link is here: https://cartalyst.com/manual/converter/2.0

I'm following official instruction and getting

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()

I feel like `Cartalyst\Converter\Laravel\ConverterServiceProvider` is not livable.

How else can I install it?

They have "Native" way, but in laravel case where would I put their "native" code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Illuminate\Foundation\Application::share()` method was removed in Laravel 5.4, in favor of the `singleton()` method.

Do you *need* to use v2.0 of this package? 3.0 was released specifically to stay up-to-date with Laravel. I suggest using the most recent version instead of the 2.0 branch.

https://cartalyst.com/manual/converter/3.0